# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/project'

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, nativescript, backend

I have this problem when I try to create a component, I already try to install these:

```
npm install -D @angular/cli

npm i --save-dev @nativescript/schematics
```

But they did not work for me.

I really do not know the problem of this dependency and why always the problems is @schematics for me

I am running:
`Angular 10.0.1`
`npm     6.14.5`
`nativescript 6.7.4`

Thanks for any help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2hqp.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an issue with @schematics/angular 10.0.1, tried 9.1.0 and works for me.

```
npm uninstall @schematics/angular
npm install @schematics/angular@9.1.0
```

Comment: Beautiful, It works now, Thanks @melo for your Help. I Downgraded the version to this one and also cleaned the cache. `npm uninstall @schematics/angular`
`npm cache clean`
`npm install @schematics/angular@9.1.8`

Comment: After trying different ways, this works smoothly